# MySQL utf8mb4 on Amazon RDS: global variables set correctly but variables not set

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to convert my Amazon RDS server to use `utf8mb4` encoding instead of `utf8`. I've followed the guide [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) and it has worked for the most part (global variables are set through my new parameter group in RDS), but my system variables are not setting correctly which means that I'm not able to utilize the new encoding.

When I run:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

I see:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8               |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

Which is obviously incorrect, but when I run:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

I see:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

This is correct, but for some reason these global values are not setting the server when I restart the server. I can correctly set the variables manually after restarts, but I don't understand why they aren't setting initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It was an issue with my local installation of MySQL - not the server. I had to change the default encoding that it sent and it worked great from there.

Comment: I have the same trouble now. Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @ykensuke9 same here, see my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify Aaron's answer, this was (at least for us) caused by the character set/collation of our **connection** to the database; the database itself is set up correctly. When you use any client to connect to the db -- whether it be SQLyog, MySQL Workbench, built in client or any other -- there is a character set and collation associated with that *connection*. Thus you need to need to change this *connection* charset/collation to utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci, and the values of

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

will then all show correctly. If you take a close look at the "problem" values in the original question you'll notice they are _client, _connection etc. which should have given me an obvious clue that the problem was with my mysql client and not the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was because I had skipped the instruction (in the original linked guide) to modify /etc/my.cnf:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```